# How can I create labels in VirtualBox like this video?

Tags: virtualbox

In t[his video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iVwom2NqPlY), I saw a fold-able label in the VM list, how was that created? I'm running VBOX 4.2 OSE as well, but didn't spot where to configure it.

```
> SERVER  // can be folded
  VM 1 
  VM 2

> Label 2
  VM 1
  VM 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press `Machine > Group` and you can rename the group. When there is more than 1 group you can collapse it.

Comment: I don't have a `Group` entry in the `Machine` menu. Which version are you running?

Comment: @Marco I am running 4.2.0 r43316

Comment: I am on 4.1.18 r78361, maybe they added the feature in 4.2